# Uploading from iPhone to iTunes Match Library

Tags: iphone, itunes, itunes-match

I have used iTunes Match for years to upload MP3s from my Mac to the cloud library. I then listen to them on my iPhone using the Music app.

But I want to know if there is a way to upload items using the iPhone instead of my Mac? There are many reasons I want to do this, One of which is I’m sometimes away from my computer for long periods of time but my phone is always with me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not exactly what you are looking for but in case you can't find an exact solution, here is an alternative:

Assuming you are getting the MP3s off of the internet, Safari should automatically save the MP3 file into the Downloads folder on iCloud. You can listen to the MP3 by tapping on it in the **Downloads folder** under **iCloud Drive** in the **Files app**. You can also move the MP3 to another folder under the iCloud Drive after selecting the MP3 if you want to keep the downloaded MP3s together in a separate folder. However, files downloaded as such will not be part of your iTunes / Apple Music library.

Comment: My goal is to make the MP3s part of my iTunes/ Apple Music library using only my phone. I appreciate my MP3s organized into albums on the iOS Music app